# Check box attributes checked is true, but tick is not shown

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have two check boxes, that I want to make to behave like they are radio buttons (only one of them is checked at time).

So, I have easy found a jQuery solution that should do the trick:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    var group = "input:checkbox[name='"+$(this).attr("name")+"']";
    $(group).attr("checked",false);
    $(this).attr("checked",true);
});
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="radio">
    <label for="q_is_active_true">Is active</label>
    <input name="radio_buttons" type="hidden" value="0"><input id="q_is_active_true" name="radio_buttons" type="checkbox" value="1">
    <label for="q_is_active_false">Is not active</label>
    <input name="radio_buttons" type="hidden" value="0"><input id="q_is_active_false" name="radio_buttons" type="checkbox" value="1">
</div>
```

But when I click on one of the check boxes, even its "check" attribute is set to "checked" no tick is shown:

[image]

[image]

Comment: why do you have the same name "radio_buttons"?

Comment: @Sergio to make a group i believe :)

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui That doesn't work with checkboxes.

Comment: @alex that's what he is trying to achieve making checkboxes as radio buttons IDK why?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to be setting the checked status by it's [**prop**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)erty to achieve what you want:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    var group = "input:checkbox[name='"+$(this).attr("name")+"']";
    $(group).prop("checked", false);
    $(this).prop("checked", true);
});
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/FGecS/)

Comment: doesn't attr() do the same thing? if not then what's the difference between them?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Answer (score 6):

You can try it this way :

```
$('input[name=checkBoxName]').parents('span').addClass("checked");
$("input[name=checkBoxName]").prop('checked', 'checked');
```

The first line is to display the tick in the check box and the second line is to actually check it.

Comment: Is this related to a UI library, like bootstrap? I just spent a lot of time and this solved the issue. But to my knowledge just setting with `prop(...)` should work too (the checkbox is not always packed into a `span`), so I have no idea why this worked in my case.

Comment: This is to check the box using JQuery.

Comment: Only the second line is generic enough to use on other people cases.